# Mostrar productos en carrito de compra según cliente

Tags: php, bootstrap

Por favor, ayudarme en este problema con el carrito de compras en Bootstrap.

Al consultar para que aparezcan los clientes con sus productos me salen todos los clientes con los mismos productos. He visto 2 soluciones, pero ninguna me funciona.

Una me envía todos los productos de un cliente a los demás clientes y la otra no muestra ningún producto.

```php
<div id="collapse<?php echo $f['id']; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $f['id']; ?>" data-parent="#accordionExample">
    <div class="card-body">
        <p>Nombre Cliente: <?php echo $f['nombre']; ?></p>
        <p>Teléfono: <?php echo $f['telefono']; ?></p>
        <p>Status: <b><?php echo $f['status']; ?></b> </p>
        <p>Email: <?php echo $f['email']; ?></p>
        <p class="h6">Datos de envío</p>

        <?php
            $re = $conexion->query("select * from envios where id_venta = " . $f['id']) or die($conexion->error);
            $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($re);
        ?>

        <p>Dirección: <?php echo $fila[3]; ?></p>
        <p>Zona: <?php echo $fila[4]; ?></p>
        <p>C.P: <?php echo $fila[5]; ?></p>
        
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Fragancia</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <?php
                $re = $conexion->query("select productos_venta.*,productos.nombre,productos.fragancia
                from productos_venta inner join productos
                on productos_venta.id_producto = productos.id
                where productos_venta.id_producto = " . $f['id_venta']) or die($conexion->error); // id_venta

            **// $re=$conexion->query("select productos_venta.*, productos.nombre, productos.fragancia from productos_venta inner join productos on productos_venta.id_producto = productos.id where productos_venta.id_venta = id_venta")or die($conexion->error);**

            while ($f2 = mysqli_fetch_array($re)) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $f2['id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $f2['nombre'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $f2['precio'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $f2['fragancia'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $f2['cantidad'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $f2['subtotal'];?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Muchas gracias por la atención

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Especialmente punto 2. Saludos :D